# Get all records with specified properties between a certain date range

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I am passing in two dates formatted as `MM-DD-YYYY` which is a date range. I need to query all records within that range and include specified fields. I've had no luck.

Part of a record in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id": "some ID",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2015-06-26T13:02:12.121Z"
    },
```

Query:

```
var Start = '09-07-2015' 

var End = '09-14-2015'
```

If I do:

```
    var query = Order.find({
        date : {
            $lt : End,
            $gt : Start
        }
    });
```

I get the full document within the week ranges as expected. However, I want to specify the fields to return rather than full document. So I've tried using grouping and project to specify those fields:

```
    var query = Order.aggregate(
        {
            $match :
            {
                date: {
                    $gte: start,
                    $lt: end
                }
            },
            $group:
            {
                cust_ID: '$request.headers.customer_id',
                wholesaler_ID: '$request.headers.wholesalerID'
            }
        }
    );
```

Likewise: I've also tried it using project to get the results I want. I thought maybe it won't match on a date string like `09-07-2015`, so I included the ISO date directly. Still no luck... the query comes back undefined or empty:

```
    var query = Order.aggregate(
        {
            $project:
            {
                date: 'date',
                cust_ID: '$request.headers.custID',
                wholesaler_ID: '$request.headers.wholesalerID'
            }
        },
        {
            $match :
            {
                date: {
                    $gte: "2014-12-09T21:02:56.872Z",
                    $lt: "2015-12-09T21:02:56.872Z"
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = Order.find({
    date : {
        $lt : End,
        $gt : Start
    }}, {cust_ID:1, wholeseller_ID:1}
);
```

This will work.

I just tested this using Robomongo

```
db.getCollection('offerdb').find({time_posted:{$gt: '2015-10-21T21:40:04+05:30', $lte:'2015-12-14T05:53:14+05:30'}},{_id:1, merchant_id:1})
```

Works like a charm for me.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work. I don't think that syntax is correct

Comment: I have posted the shell code as well that I have tested, please check it. Maybe I haven't edited the code properly.

Comment: I have edited the code, a bracket wasn't ordered properly. Run it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in mongo shell

```
use dbname

db.collection_name.find({date: {$gte: ISODate('2015-09-07 00:00:00'), $lte: ISODate('2015-09-14 23:59:59.999999')}},{'cust_ID':1,'_id':0,'wholeseller_ID':1})
```